# Jasmine withArgs expected types

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, ngxs

I have been going through and upgrading my angular version from 10 to 13. So that I could use typescript 4.6. In doing this, I screwed up some types in my tests and was curious if anyone else has experienced this.
The error I am getting is:

`Argument of type '(state: ExampleStateModel) => Example' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateToken<unknown> | AsymmetricMatcher<any>'.ts(2345)`

I can get all my tests to compile and run by just using: `@ts-ignore` but I would like to avoid that as my solution if I can. Here is some code

fails

```
 store = TestBed.inject(Store);
 spyOn(store, 'selectSnapshot')
   .withArgs(ExampleState.clinic).and.returnValue({ id: 1 })
```

works

```
 store = TestBed.inject(Store);
 // @ts-ignore
 spyOn(store, 'selectSnapshot').withArgs(ExampleState.clinic).and.returnValue({ id: 1 })
```

Example State

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleState {
  @Selector()
  public static clinic(state: ExampleStateModel) {
    return state.clinic;
  }
}
```

I have also tried running `npm i -D jasmine@latest jasmine-core@latest @types/jasmine@latest`

I guess my question boils down how to use `withArgs()` using a ngxs store. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going with @ts-ignore. Playing around with the correct versions on all my packages became too big of a headache when @ts-ignore just works.

Comment: That does not work for me.

```
Error: Spy 'selectSnapshot' received a call with arguments [ Function ] but all configured strategies specify other arguments.
```

Comment: My guess is that the error you’re seeing is a little different. I’d need to see what you’re actually doing to be of more help

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing as in your example. But in Angular 16 and latest version of Ngxs. Here is a https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yk3i1h?file=src%2Fstore%2Fstore.state.spec.ts